# Why not getting output with arrow function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

When i'm trying buildGraph function with normal function its working properly but with arrow function getting empty obj as output. Help needed.

```js
var roads = [
    "Alice's House-Bob's House", "Alice's House-Cabin",
    "Alice's House-Post Office", "Bob's House-Town Hall",
    "Daria's House-Ernie's House", "Daria's House-Town Hall",
    "Ernie's House-Grete's House", "Grete's House-Farm",
    "Grete's House-Shop", "Marketplace-Farm",
    "Marketplace-Post Office", "Marketplace-Shop",
    "Marketplace-Town Hall", "Shop-Town Hall"
   ];

let buildGraph = (edges) => {
    let obj = {}
    let addEdge = (from, to) => (
        obj[from] === null ? obj[from] = [to] : obj[from]?.push(to)
    )
    edges.map(r => r.split("-")).map(([from, to]) => addEdge(from, to))
    return obj;
}
console.log(buildGraph(roads))   // Output: {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `null` with `undefined`. If a `key` is not found in an object it returns `undefined` not `null`.

```js
var roads = [
  "Alice's House-Bob's House",
  "Alice's House-Cabin",
  "Alice's House-Post Office",
  "Bob's House-Town Hall",
  "Daria's House-Ernie's House",
  "Daria's House-Town Hall",
  "Ernie's House-Grete's House",
  "Grete's House-Farm",
  "Grete's House-Shop",
  "Marketplace-Farm",
  "Marketplace-Post Office",
  "Marketplace-Shop",
  "Marketplace-Town Hall",
  "Shop-Town Hall",
];

let buildGraph = (edges) => {
  let obj = {};
  let addEdge = (from, to) =>
    obj[from] === undefined ? (obj[from] = [to]) : obj[from]?.push(to);
  edges.map((r) => r.split("-")).map(([from, to]) => addEdge(from, to));
  return obj;
};

console.log(buildGraph(roads));
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not the arrow function, it's this comparison:

```
obj[from] === null
```

The `===` operator performs an exact type-comparison, and for properties which don't exist on an object the *exact type* of the property is not `null`, it's `undefined`.  So that comparison is `false` and the property is never added to the object.

Compare it to `undefined` instead:

```js
var roads = [
    "Alice's House-Bob's House", "Alice's House-Cabin",
    "Alice's House-Post Office", "Bob's House-Town Hall",
    "Daria's House-Ernie's House", "Daria's House-Town Hall",
    "Ernie's House-Grete's House", "Grete's House-Farm",
    "Grete's House-Shop", "Marketplace-Farm",
    "Marketplace-Post Office", "Marketplace-Shop",
    "Marketplace-Town Hall", "Shop-Town Hall"
   ];

let buildGraph = (edges) => {
    let obj = {}
    let addEdge = (from, to) => (
        obj[from] === undefined ? obj[from] = [to] : obj[from]?.push(to)
    )
    edges.map(r => r.split("-")).map(([from, to]) => addEdge(from, to))
    return obj;
}
console.log(buildGraph(roads))   // Output: {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `.reduce()`. Its often used if you want to group something together

```js
var roads = [
    "Alice's House-Bob's House", "Alice's House-Cabin",
    "Alice's House-Post Office", "Bob's House-Town Hall",
    "Daria's House-Ernie's House", "Daria's House-Town Hall",
    "Ernie's House-Grete's House", "Grete's House-Farm",
    "Grete's House-Shop", "Marketplace-Farm",
    "Marketplace-Post Office", "Marketplace-Shop",
    "Marketplace-Town Hall", "Shop-Town Hall"
   ];

let result = roads.reduce((obj, road) => {
  let [from, to] = road.split("-")
  obj[from] ? obj[from].push(to) : obj[from] = [to]
  return obj
},{})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `obj[from] === null` comparison

Sometimes the 'double equal' still makes sense:

```js
var roads = [
    "Alice's House-Bob's House", "Alice's House-Cabin",
    "Alice's House-Post Office", "Bob's House-Town Hall",
    "Daria's House-Ernie's House", "Daria's House-Town Hall",
    "Ernie's House-Grete's House", "Grete's House-Farm",
    "Grete's House-Shop", "Marketplace-Farm",
    "Marketplace-Post Office", "Marketplace-Shop",
    "Marketplace-Town Hall", "Shop-Town Hall"
   ];

let buildGraph = (edges) => {
    let obj = {}
    let addEdge = (from, to) => 
        (obj[from] == null ? obj[from] = [to] : obj[from]?.push(to))
    
    edges.map(r => r.split("-")).map(([from, to]) => addEdge(from, to))
    return obj;
}
console.log(buildGraph(roads))   // Output: {}
```

That way you're comparing to undefined or null in one step